# Linux sed program don't work with PS1 environmental variable

Tags: bash, sed

How can I connect `sed` program with export PS1 environmental variable? I want to replace my `$HOME` path with `~` when I'm on root (when I'm not on root then is no problem with it and `$HOME` is automatically replaced with `~`). I'm trying something like this:`export PS1="$(sed 's/\/home\/\myname/g' '\e[1m\e[31mroot\e[0m@\[\033[0;34m\]\w\[\033[0;37m\]$ ')"` bur then error occurred `sed: can't read \e[1m\e[31mroot\e[0m@\[\033[0;34m\]\w\[\033[0;37m\]$ : No such file or directory`

Comment: note you are saying `sed 's/X/Y/g 'things'`, so `sed` sees those `things` as a file.

Answer (score 1):

When you put something on the command line, sed interprets it as a file name. To process a text string, use something like: `echo abcd | sed 's/b/X/'`. So, in order to modify PS1, you would use `export PS1=$(echo "$PS1" | sed 's/.../.../')`.